# Arduino Yun run shell command with variable

Tags: shell, variables, arduino, arduino-yun

I need help on this part of a project I am making, I need to run a shell command and pass a variable either string or char to it.

```
p.runShellCommand("madplay /mnt/sda1/");
```

Above is my shell command which works, however I want to put a variable after the last slash

```
p.runShellCommand("madplay /mnt/sda1/variable");
```

The above code is what I have tried, replacing variable with my variable and didn't seem to work.

I have also tried this which seems to work

```
String hey = "madplay /mnt/sda1/worldOfTomorrow.mp3";
p.runShellCommand(hey);
```

Comment: `String command= "madplay /mnt/sda1/";
String var = "worldOfTomorrow.mp3";
p.runShellCommand(command+var);` Did you try something like that?

Comment: Thank you so much that worked great

Answer (score 0):

It's just string concatenation:

```
String command= "madplay /mnt/sda1/";
String var = "worldOfTomorrow.mp3";
p.runShellCommand(command+var);
```

Now, write in `var` with desired function:

```
String command= "madplay /mnt/sda1/";
String var = getNameOfFile();
p.runShellCommand(command+var);
...
public String getNameOfFile(){
//code retrieving your desired variable by Serial/SDcard/Ethernet....
}
```